# Is the White Worm character from Solo, a reference to Bram Stoker's Lair of the White Worm?

Tags: star-wars, reference, solo-a-star-wars-story

At the beginning of ***Solo: A Star Wars Story***, we are introduced to a younger Han Solo and his girlfriend Qi'ra who are under the thumb of some criminal organization led by an alien that is literally **a White Worm-like creature**, who lives in a water hole, and is sensitive to light.

[image: picture with blue tones. Han Solo and Qi'ra surrounded by aliens]

This scene and creature is very similar to the concept and creature presented in Bram Stoker's horror story, *[Lair of the White Worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lair_of_the_White_Worm)* (1911).

**Is *Solo* intentionally referencing Bram Stoker's work?**

Comment: I found the answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, Mother Proxima and The White Worms gang are homage to the novel!

From Jon Kasdan's useless facts sheets, referring to *Solo: A Star Wars Story* via
[Jon Kasdan's Twitter Post](https://twitter.com/JonKasdan/status/1040529501870944256). (See #2)

[image: Twitter Kasdan]

And reconfirmed at [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/White_Worms)

> The White Worms were first mentioned in the 2018 adventure book Choose
> Your Destiny: A Han & Chewie Adventure, written by Cavan Scott. They
> first appeared on-screen in the 2018 Star Wars Anthology film Solo: A
> Star Wars Story. **The gang's name was an homage to Bram Stoker's 1911
> novel The Lair of the White Worm.**